# Do we need a .yml file in our phone by Aruco Marker?

Tags: swift, xcode, opencv, yaml, aruco

I am using the Aruco Marker for iOS version, but I could not detect any of markers since there is no file called camera_parameters.yml on my phone. I read the documents since we use a camera instead of images, we need to make .yml file to detect the marker. However, I am confused how can create .yml file and what to put inside.

I created the file and inserted into my phone, but still,​ it is an empty or wrong content in the file, I cannot run the application.

Comment: You can hard-code your camera's intrinsic matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your code, what do you mean the camera's intrinsic matrix?
so i don't have to create the yml file?

Comment: That's the content of the file `camera_parameters.yml `. For more information see [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was wondering why do we need a calibrate file even we just want to detect

Comment: I thought we need the yml file when we want to calibrate the marker